# How to execute oracle query that was saved in a .txt file

Tags: oracle, toad

I have too long oracle query that I saved in .txt file. and I am using Toad to execute that..

some it is too difficult to open such large code file and execute the code..
Is there any query that I can execute and give path to file that execute the code placed in that file.

For example something like that:

```
 Execute code C:/My Code/code1.txt;
```

Comment: Open in notepad - CTRL+A, CTRL+C in notepad. Cursor to TOAD. CTRL+V

Comment: We don't want to open the code file and manually select code and execute ...to reduce the risk of code change or mistakenly delete or update...

Comment: first you save your txt file to sql format like code1.sql ant try,  http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/script.php

Comment: [Like this](http://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-for-oracle/w/toad_for_oracle_wiki/118.how-do-i-run-very-large-scripts)? Same as SQL\*Plus, if that's correct. (I don't have Toad to check but I'm sure I've seen that before...)

Comment: SQL > @/oracle/scripts/script.sql

Comment: I try this way but we cannt start with SQL>

Comment: i am looking for same thing but syntax should be different

Comment: The "SQL >" part in the TechOnTheNet article is the SQL\*Plus command prompt. It is not part of the command itself. Did you look at the ToadWorld article I linked to earlier?

Comment: "It's not working" isn't very helpful. Update your question to show what you've tried and the error you get, as well as the content of a sample file (not your large one; get it working with a trivial script first). Also say exactly where you're running it; I don't use Toad but if it has different types of windows say which one you're using.

Comment: As reading from the link you send; http://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-for-oracle/w/toad_for_oracle_wiki/118.how-do-i-run-very-large-scripts I did try the syntax that is written in there it didn't work         
•In the MOE, simply type @c:\path\to\script\script_name.sql


•then press F5.

Comment: Again, what does "didn't work" mean? What happened?  Error message?  “In a dark place we find ourselves, and a little more knowledge lights our way.” – Yoda

Answer (score 1):

If you have a TOAD locally installed, you can use

```
@C:/My Code/code1.txt
```

This works from an editor tab in Toad 12.10.0.30 with the slashes going either direction and pressing F5 or "execute as script". The file can end in .txt or .sql but it is better to use .sql extension as it represents what the file contains.

It also works when using other programs such as sqlplus or sqlDeveloper

Comment: Just adding my confirmation that this works from an editor tab in Toad 12.10.0.30 with the slashes going either direction and pressing F5 or "execute as script". The file can end in .txt or .sql but I would strongly recommend .sql as that better represents what the file contains.

Comment: @Gary_W Thanks for checking it, I will edit my answer accordingly to your contribution.